# How can I style this div layout with css?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to get four divs styled as in this image.

[image]

I've tried with using `float:left` but I either get all the divs stuck up on the right side of Div1
or all of them stuck underneath Div1. I believe I need to do a `clear` somewhere, is that right?

NB.
Div2 and Div3 may be different heights.

***Updated***.
Thankyou for the answers so far, they are almost what I needed. To add to the question, is it possible to get this look when the DivContainer doesnt have a fixed width?

Comment: http://www.blueprintcss.org/ ftw

Comment: For more explanation on the floating techniques given in answers below, see http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/.  For more tested two and three column layouts (what you  have here is essentially a two column in a two column), see http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Css_Layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#wrap { width:730px; overflow:auto; padding:20px; }
#div1 { width:500px; float:left; height:200px; margin-bottom:20px;  }
#div2 { width:237px; float:left; clear:left; height:150px; margin-right:20px; }
#div3 { width:237px; float:left; height:170px; }
#div4 { width:200px; float:right; height:500px; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/MNjyg/show/

---

Update:

```
#wrap { overflow:auto; }
#div1{ background:yellow; width:70%; float:left;  }
#div2{ background:red; width:35%; float:left; clear:left; }
#div3{ background:green; width:35%; float:left;  }
#div4{ background:blue; width:30%; float:right; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Cm7b7/6/

Note: The 4 DIV's have their widths defined in percentages. It is important that you don't define margins, padding, or borders on those DIV's because that would mess up the percentages. If you need padding and borders, define them on child elements instead.

Comment: Thankyou!... is it possible to do this with out fixing the width of wrap? ie http://jsfiddle.net/Cm7b7/4/ - looks ok until you extend the width of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Floats are the fastest way to go and most flexible with dynamic height content. You'd have to take some liberties with the document order. Meaning move *div4* after *div1*.

See an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/Wsf53/

Comment: thats pretty close, but I need the Div4 to 'stick' to the right of Div1? Is that possible with giving the container a fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {float:left;}
#div2 { float:left; clear:left;}
#div3 {float:left;}
#div4 {float:right;}
```

that should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the order of the div's? For instance, make the right column div2? So you could float everything left except div 2 which would be floated right?

---

> Yes, I can change the order of the divs if that makes a difference.

Then I'd order them so that the second div is the right column. And then something similar to:

```
#div1{width: 400px; float: left;}
#div2{width: 200px; float: right;height: 600px;}
#div3, #div4{width: 200px; float: left;}
#div3{background-color: green;}
```

For example: http://dev.tylerc.net/divs.html

Comment: yes, I can change the order of the divs if that makes a difference

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't create a div that has father of the div1 div2 e div3 only? 
Do you try it?